# Find length of edge $c$ given the lengths of $a, b$ and $r$ (the radius of circle).

Tags: geometry, triangles

I made some problem and i get stuck to solve it!

The diagram for the question is: 
[image: here]: 
Find the length of edge $\enspace\pmb{c}\enspace$ in terms of $\enspace\pmb{a}$,$\enspace\pmb{b},\enspace$ and $\enspace\pmb{r},\enspace$ where $\enspace r\enspace$ is the radius of the circle shown in the diagram.

I think we can find the lengtn of the chord $\enspace c\enspace$  using certain angles and the radius of circle. I also think $\enspace\cos\left(A+B\right)\enspace$ is the angle we need. I want to solve it, but it is too difficult.

**Edit:**
I solved some equations but the result is too complex!

This is the result for $c$ (for more information see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHRIs.png)): 
$c=\sqrt{2r^2(1-cos(\theta+\varphi))}$ (from law of cosines)

And for $cos(\theta+\varphi)$ we have: 
$\large{cos(\theta+\varphi)=\frac{(2r^2-a^2)(2r^2-b^2)-ab\sqrt{(4r^2-a^2)(4r^2-b^2)}}{4r^4}}$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Diagram1]

The diagram was originally posted hoping it would help OP to follow the hints given by @Andrei in his answer. However, OP’s comment shows that he now has some difficulties with our diagram itself. Therefore, we decided to add a solution.

First thing, you do not need to use inverse trigonometric functions to determine the value of $\enspace c\enspace$.

Consider the right angled triangle $OEB$. We obtain the following relationships from this triangle.
$$ \sin\left(\alpha\right) = \dfrac{a}{2r} \tag{1}$$
$$OE=\dfrac{\sqrt{4r^2-a^2}}{2} \quad\text{(obtained using Pythagoras Theorem)}$$
$$ \cos\left(\alpha\right) = \dfrac{\sqrt{4r^2-a^2}}{2r} \tag{2}$$

Consider the right angled triangle $ADO$. We use it to establish the following relationships.
$$ \sin\left(\beta\right) = \dfrac{b}{2r} \tag{3}$$
$$OD=\dfrac{\sqrt{4r^2-b^2}}{2} \quad\text{(obtained using Pythagoras Theorem)}$$
$$ \cos\left(\beta\right) = \dfrac{\sqrt{4r^2-b^2}}{2r} \tag{4}$$

Please note that, according to the Theorem 51 (Euclid III.20.), $\measuredangle BAC = \measuredangle BOE = \alpha$ and $\measuredangle CBA = \measuredangle DOA = \beta$.

Now we can express $\sin\left(\theta\right)$ using (1), (2), (3), and (4) as shown below.
$$\sin\left(\theta\right) = \sin\left(180-\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\right) = \sin\left(\alpha+\beta \right) = \sin\left(\alpha\right) \cos\left(\beta\right) + \sin\left(\beta\right) \cos\left(\alpha\right) $$
$$\therefore \quad \sin\left(\theta\right) = \dfrac{a}{2r}\dfrac{\sqrt{4r^2-b^2}}{2r}+\dfrac{b}{2r} \dfrac{\sqrt{4r^2-a^2}}{2r}=\dfrac{a\sqrt{4r^2-b^2}+b\sqrt{4r^2-a^2}}{4r^2} \tag{5}$$

Finally, we apply sine-rule to $\triangle ACB$ to obtain the required expression for $\enspace c$.
$$\dfrac{c}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}= \dfrac{a}{\sin\left(\alpha\right)}$$
$$c=a\dfrac{\sin\left(\alpha\right)}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}= \dfrac{a\sqrt{4r^2-b^2}+b\sqrt{4r^2-a^2}}{2r} \tag{6}$$

We can also apply the law of cosines to $\triangle ACB$ to find the value of $\enspace c^2\enspace$, i.e.,
$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 – 2ab\cos\left(\theta\right).$$
However, the expression obtained by this method is a little bit more complicated than the one given as (6) above. We leave it to OP to find it.

Comment: thanks, but i don't know the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and i don't want to use inverse trigonometry functions, see my new answer for what i found...

Comment: We have added our solution to show that you do not need to use inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: This is what i was trying to find, Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

- Put some letters in the corners of the triangle. Say $A$ is opposite of side $a$ and so on. The center of the circle is $O$
- draw perpendiculars from $O$ to the three sides. They will split angles $\angle AOB$ and so on in half.
- write the sine of the angles in terms of $r, a/2, b/2, c/2$
- what's the relationship between angles?

Comment: Thanks for your hints, I got all of them but not the last one, whats the relationship? Are you talking about sine rule?

Comment: $\angle AOC+\angle COB=\angle AOB$